# Codeigniter IF inside $this->db->select

Tags: codeigniter

i have codeigniter code

```
$this->db->select("items.name as name, items.category as category, items.supplier_id as supplier_id, items.item_number as item_number,
 items.product_id as product_id, items.description as description, 
items.size as size, items.tax_included as tax_included, items.cost_price as cost_price, 
if(price_tiers.name='".$hasilsplit1."',items_tier_prices.unit_price,items.unit_price) as unit_price, items.promo_price as promo_price, 
items.start_date as start_date, items.end_date as end_date, items.reorder_level as reorder_level, items.item_id as item_id, items.allow_alt_description as allow_alt_description, items.is_serialized as is_serialized, items.image_id as image_id, items.override_default_tax as override_default_tax, items.is_service as is_service, items.deleted as deleted");
    $this->db->from('items');
    $this->db->join('items_tier_prices','items_tier_prices.item_id=items.item_id','left');
    $this->db->join("price_tiers","price_tiers.id=items_tier_prices.tier_id and price_tiers.name='".$hasilsplit1."'","left");
    $this->db->where('items.item_id', $hasilsplit0);
    $this->db->where('items.deleted', 0);
```

it generates error on part:

```
if(price_tiers.name='".$hasilsplit1."',items_tier_prices.unit_price,items.unit_price) as unit_price
```

the error is:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as unit_price, `items`.`promo_price` as promo_price, `items`.`start_date` as sta' at line 1

how to write IF syntax correctly inside $this->db->select?

when i var_dump, it shows

SELECT `items`.`name` as name, `items`.`category` as category, `items`.`supplier_id` as supplier_id, `items`.`item_number` as item_number, `items`.`product_id` as product_id, `items`.`description` as description, `items`.`size` as size, `items`.`tax_included` as tax_included, `items`.`cost_price` as cost_price, if(price_tiers.name='Jendela Swing Double J106', `items_tier_prices`.`unit_price`, `items`.`unit_price)` as unit_price, `items`.`promo_price` as promo_price, `items`.`start_date` as start_date, `items`.`end_date` as end_date, `items`.`reorder_level` as reorder_level, `items`.`item_id` as item_id, `items`.`allow_alt_description` as allow_alt_description, `items`.`is_serialized` as is_serialized, `items`.`image_id` as image_id, `items`.`override_default_tax` as override_default_tax, `items`.`is_service` as is_service, `items`.`deleted` as deleted FROM (`items`) LEFT JOIN `items_tier_prices` ON `items_tier_prices`.`item_id`=`items`.`item_id` LEFT JOIN `price_tiers` ON `price_tiers`.`id`=`items_tier_prices`.`tier_id` and price_tiers.name='Jendela Swing Double J106' WHERE `items`.`item_id` = '1' AND `items`.`deleted` = 0

it seems if blocks getting character `
Thanks

Comment: what error are you getting? you haven't specified.

Comment: hi @Farside, pls check edited Question.thx

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to check the manual, and to try to disable escaping when [compiling `SELECT`](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#selecting-data):

> `$this->db->select()` accepts an optional *second parameter*. If you set it to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table names. This is useful if you need a compound select statement where automatic escaping of fields may break them.

And the second recommendation would be to escape SQL query, when you are using raw data, for example:

```
$this->db->escape($someString); // instead of using $someString when concatenating string for query.
```

Comment: hi Farside thanks i have put FALSE as second parameter and select works with if. thanks :)

Comment: glad to help! feel free to upvote/or accept the answer if found useful, @mlms133  ;)